# Initializing Vuex parameter with a value from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, quasar

I have this code for Vuex and I wanted to initialize a parameter's default value to a value from a Vuex array. How do I do this?

```
passcode: this.state.passcodes[0].value
```

It results to an error stating

```
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    passcodes: [
      {
        label: 'Pass1',
        value: '123456',
      },
      {
        label: 'Pass2',
        value: '654321',
      }
    ],
    data: [
      {
        name: '',
        passcode: this.state.passcode[0].value
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

How do I do this??

Answer (score 0):

```js
const passcodes = [
  {
    label: 'Pass1',
    value: '123456',
  },
  {
    label: 'Pass2',
    value: '654321',
  }
]

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    passcodes,
    data: [
      {
        name: '',
        passcode: passcodes[0].value
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: Any other way we can do it from inside the Vuex store?

Comment: Not in the way you want. You'd have to do a mutation after creating the store.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Getter like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    passcodes: [
      { label: 'Pass1', value: 123456 },
      { label: 'Pass2', value: 654321 }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    defaultPass: state => {
      return state.passcodes[0]
    }
  }
})
```

You can then access your default setting via `store.getters.defaultPass`.

Or a mutation like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    passcodes: [
      { label: 'Pass1', value: 123456 },
      { label: 'Pass2', value: 654321 }
    ],
    defaultPass: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    default(state, n): {
      state.defaultPass = state.passcodes[n]
    }
  }
})
```

You can then set your default value with `store.commit('default', 0)`.